# android positioning a Bitmap matrix

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, position

Can you explain to me why the px and py are not the actual coordinates that a `Bitmap` is to be placed at? I've been trying to understand the matrix but I only understand the scaled x and scaled y. Here's and example:

```
float newBitmapWidth = (float) (canvas.getWidth()/((float)800/345)*1.5); 
float scaledWidth = newBitmapWidth / 1697;
float newBitmapHeight = (float) (canvas.getHeight()/((float)480/100)*1.5); 
float scaledHeight = newBitmapHeight / 492;
CarMatrix.postScale(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, 100, 100);
```

So, the matrix scales my 1697x492 bitmap to 517.5x150 perfectly. Exact amount of pixels/screen resolution occupied... But when I try to position the `Bitmap` with px and py, the image doesn't start on them in my case: 100,100.